# Error de conexión al insertar a Mysql

Tags: java, mysql

Me conecto a una base de datos MySQL,  pero no me deja insertar datos.

```
package javaapplication2;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

/**
 *
 * @author Maister
 */
public class RegistroBiblio {

    Connection cn;
    Statement st;
    ResultSet rs;
    String con, nombre="jose", dia="lunes 28";


    public void conectar(){
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            cn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/biblioteca?user=root&password=");
            System.out.println("Conexion");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    public void cerrar() throws SQLException{
        cn.close();
        System.out.println("Cerrar");
    }
    public void insertar(String nombre, String dia){
        try {
            conectar();
            con="insert into tabla (nombre, dia) values ('"+nombre+"', '"+dia+"')";
            st.execute(con);
            System.out.println("Insertar good");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
        public void insertar2(String nombre, String dia){
        try {
            conectar();
            con="insert into p (uno, dos) values ('"+nombre+"', '"+dia+"')";
            st.execute(con);
            System.out.println("Insertar good");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    public void select(String nombre){
        try {
            conectar();
            con="select * from tabla where nombre='"+nombre+"'";
            rs=st.executeQuery(con);
            while(rs.next()){
                nombre=rs.getString("nombre");
                dia=rs.getString("dia");
                System.out.println("Select");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        RegistroBiblio a=new RegistroBiblio();
        a.insertar("Jose", "Jueves");
    }

}
```

¿Cómo resolver el siguiente error?

> run:
>
> Conexion
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> at javaaplication2.RegistroBiblio.insertar(**RegistroBiblio.java:45**)
>
> at javaaplication2.RegistroBiblio.main(**RegistroBiblio.java:81**)
>
> **C:\Users\Maister\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53**:
>   Java returned:1
>
> BUILD FAILED (total time:0 seconds)

Comment: amigo especifica mas cosas para ayudarte, que base de datos es, que problema puntual tienes etc..

Answer (score 2):

Si cierro los ojos a todos los problemas de diseños que veo, el error específico que tienes debe venir de esta línea:

```
st.execute(con); // st debe estar a null
```

Porque si me fijo en tu `main`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    RegistroBiblio a=new RegistroBiblio();
    a.insertar("Jose", "Jueves");
}
```

<strike>...nunca ejecutas el método `conectar()` que se ocupa de crear la conección a la  base de datos, de modo que `cn`, `st`, etc... deben estar a `null` todavía.</strike> Corrección: sí ejecutas `conectar()` desde el método `insertar()`, pero `conectar()` nunca inicializa la variable `st`, de modo que el problema es el mismo: `st` está a `null`.

Interesantemente, hoy también se hizo la pregunta siguiente: [¿Por qué es considerado una mala práctica utilizar variables globales?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/29177/por-qu%C3%A9-es-considerado-una-mala-pr%C3%A1ctica-utilizar-variables-globales). Creo que tu caso es un buen ejemplo de porqué es importante evitar las variables globales.

También te recomiendo de revisar el hilo siguiente: [¿Qué es la inyección SQL y cómo puedo evitarla?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/10518/qu%C3%A9-es-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-y-c%C3%B3mo-puedo-evitarla/).

Una recomendación más: Ya que parece que estás usando Netbeans, una herramienta excelente para desarollar programas en Java, aprende a usar el modo "Debug" para investigar y corregir estos problemas. Usando esa técnica, hubieras identificado el problema inmediatamente.

Comment: +1 por hacer notar que el codigo es vulnerable a injeccion SQL.

Comment: Como consejo para agregar a esta respuesta, las conexiones siempre deben ser inicializadas en el ámbito más reducido posible y ser reutilizada al máximo posible en este ámbito.