# como puedo hacer para usar las variables que recibo por post en todas mis paginas html

Tags: php, html

```
<?php 
    $origen = $_POST["origen"];
    $destino = $_POST["destino"];
    $pesoReal = ceil($_POST["peso"]);
    $largo = $_POST["largo"];
    $ancho = $_POST["ancho"];
    $alto = $_POST["alto"];

$pesoVolumetrico = $largo * $ancho * $alto / 5000;
if ($pesoVolumetrico > $pesoReal) {
    $pintaPeso = $pesoVolumetrico;
}else{
    $pintaPeso = $pesoReal;
}

?>
```

Comment: Usar variables de session. Sirve pero aquí dicen que es mala práctica http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/29177/por-qu%C3%A9-es-considerado-una-mala-pr%C3%A1ctica-utilizar-variables-globales XD

Comment: si, de hecho pensaba usar variables de sesion pero tambien por seguridad me recomiendan no hacerlo y quiero saber como podria resolverlo.

Comment: Creo que en la respuesta de la pregunta del link que te pegué hay opciones. Personalmente yo usaría variables globales si no son muchas. Pero parece que sí serán muchas contigo. Una opción es pasarlas de una en una recibiéndolas y seteándolas en inputs hidden en un formulario y así constantemente.

Comment: No se entiende la pregunta, amigo.  Quieres recibir esa data una sola vez y después usarla en otras páginas, como variables de sesión?

Comment: la pagina es un formulario de un cotizador, el formulario recibe datos que intruduce el publico en general, esos datos los envio por el metodo post a la siguiente pagina para poder usarlos y hacer los diferentes calculos, pero despues de hacer los calculos nesecito poder tener acceso a dichos valores en los pasos siguientes de las diferentes paginas que contiene dicho portal

Comment: Puedes usar cualquier sistema de persistencia de los que hay disponible, cookies, localStorage, variables de sesión, base de datos, cache... u otras un poco más fugaces, input ocultos o variables en la url. Dependiendo del grado de persistencia, privacidad y seguridad de los datos deberás decantarte por uno u otros.

Answer (score 1):

usa localstorage y sessionstorage

```
/*Guardando los datos en el LocalStorage*/
localStorage.setItem("Nombre", "Cualquier texto");
localStorage.setItem("Apellido", "Cualquier texto");
/*Obtener datos almacenados*/
var nombre = localStorage.getItem("Nombre");
var apellido = localStorage.getItem("Apellido");
```

Comment: no importa que este recibiendo los valores de las variables mediante post desde un formulario de otra pagina??

Comment: No se bien lo que estas intentando hacer pero puedes construir tu formulario post por ajax, y en la creación del ajax guardas las variables que vas a ocupar en todas las paginas como sessionStorage, así puedes tener los datos en cualquier pagina html.