# Usar variables que se determinaron dentro de un módulo en Javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy desarrollando lo siguiente:

- Primero, generé un array
- Luego, hice una función que hace un *[shuffle](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_Fisher-Yates)* de los valores dentro del
  array
- Mezclé los valores del array
- Mostré en diferentes variables los valores del array

Básicamente hice esto para obtener 6 valores aleatorios dentro de un rango determinado sin que se pudieran repetir.

El asunto es que quiero modularizar el *script* y no sé si conviene, ya que no puedo usar las variables con los índices del array porque quiero usar 4 valores de los 6 que tengo.

El código:

```
var autos = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];         
shuffleArray(autos);        

var valor1 = autos[0];
var valor2 = autos[1];
var valor3 = autos[2];
var valor4 = autos[3];
```

¿Cómo puedo modularizar eso y poder utilizar las variables ***valor*** como variable global?

Answer (score 1):

Primero veamos como podemos exponer nuestras variables **cuando su alcance no es global**, en el objeto `window`:

```js
(function(window) {

  "use strict";

  var autos = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

  //shuffleArray(autos);

  window.valor1 = autos[0];
  window.valor2 = autos[1];
  window.valor3 = autos[2];
  window.valor4 = autos[3];

})(window);

console.log(valor1, valor2, valor3, valor4);
// 1 2 3 4
```

---

Despues veamos como podemos modularizar:

```js
(function() {

  var ModuloAutos = function() {

    "use strict";

    var modulo = {},
      autos = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

    //shuffleArray(autos);

    modulo.valor1 = autos[0];
    modulo.valor2 = autos[1];
    modulo.valor3 = autos[2];
    modulo.valor4 = autos[3];

    return modulo;

  };

  var misAutos = new ModuloAutos();

  console.log(misAutos.valor1, misAutos.valor2, misAutos.valor3, misAutos.valor4);
  // 1 2 3 4

})();
```

---

Ya que sabemos como exponer una variable en el objeto `window` y como modularizar, podemos exponer una instancia de nuestro array:

```js
(function(window) {

  var ModuloAutos = function() {

    "use strict";

    var modulo = {},
      autos = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

    //shuffleArray(autos);

    modulo.valor1 = autos[0];
    modulo.valor2 = autos[1];
    modulo.valor3 = autos[2];
    modulo.valor4 = autos[3];

    return modulo;

  };

  window.autos = new ModuloAutos();

})(window);


console.log(autos.valor1, autos.valor2, autos.valor3, autos.valor4);
// 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: No si están en local scope, si gustas trata de acceder a la variable `ModuloAutos` fuera del IIFE.

Answer (score 1):

> ¿Cómo puedo **modularizar eso** y poder utilizar las variables valor como variable global?

La modularización siempre ha sido posible en el JavaScript *moderno*. Hay varias técnicas que puedes utilizar para este objetivo y que ciertamente son mejores que usar variables globales. En lo posible, **no uses variables globales**, tiene muchas contras y pocos pros. En [este enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/29177/por-qu%C3%A9-es-considerado-una-mala-pr%C3%A1ctica-utilizar-variables-globales) puedes ver muy buenas respuestas al respecto.

Algunas estrategias son:

- Namespaces y Module pattern
- CommonJS, AMD, UMD, etc.
- ES6 modules

---

#### Namespaces y module pattern

Un namespace o espacio de nombres, se refiere a un ente con un contexto propio y que guarda dentro distintos valores. Si has programado en C# entonces entenderás con exactitud qué es un namespace.

Por otro lado, el *module pattern* o *patrón módulo*, como su propio nombre lo indica, es un patrón de diseño creado para permitir la organización del código en módulos que, hablando en JavaScript, corresponde parcialmente a un namespace.

Este patrón se representa de la siguiente manera en JavaScript:

```js
var modulo = (() => {
  const name = 'Hola Gustavo';
  
  return {
    greet() {
      return name;
    }
  }
})();

// en otro archivo
console.log(modulo.greet());
```

Es realmente sencillo usar este patrón. Solo necesitas meter las variables y métodos en una IIFE y estarán disponibles en el módulo/namespace. Si me dices, ¿qué tiene de especial contra guardar un objeto literal en `window`? La respuesta es que tienes un mayor control de lo que ocurre dentro de dicho módulo. Por ejemplo, puedes tener variables privadas, métodos privados/públicos, y todo estará dentro de dicho contexto, lo que no ocurre si usas un objeto literal.

#### CommonJS, AMD, UMD, RequireJS, etc.

Para no extender la respuesta, voy a tratar solo de CommonJS. CommonJS es una especificación que te permite programar en módulos y exportar, tanto valores individuales como un "todo", es decir, exportar todo el contenido del módulo:

```
// archivo A.js
module.exports = {
  const privada = 'valor';

  const metodo = function () {
    // hacer algo
  }
}

// Archivo B.js
const moduleA = require('B');

moduleA.metodo();
```

Esta especificación está implementada en Node.js de forma nativa.

#### ES6

ECMAScript 6 trajo una novedad que se venía pidiendo a gritos: módulos nativos. Estos llegaron y de inmediato significaron una mejora enorme en la forma en que escribes JavaScript. ES6 modules es una especificación con una sintaxis natural, por ejemplo, para exportar un módulo:

```
// archivo A.js
export const propiedad = 123;
export default function hacerAlgo() { ... }
```

Y para importar:

```
// archivo B.js
import hacerAlgo, { propiedad } from 'A';
```

Si bien ES6 modules aún no ha sido implementado en los navegadores (salvo por Safari Tech Preview), puedes usar esta especificación y todas las de ES6 en adelante mediante [Babel](https://babeljs.io).