# variables globales en c++

Tags: c++, variables-globales

Estoy haciendo un programa con funciones y una variable global, la idea era manejar una variable global en varias funciones, no conozco como hacer funciones globales, esto es lo que intente:

```
#include<cmath>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int number=3;

void main(){
    cout<<number;
}
```

pero me marca de sintaxis en `void main(){` no tengo ni idea de el porque si se supone que `number` es una variable global.

Cual es el problema?

Comment: ¿se podria saber cual es el mensaje de error?

Comment: Es de sintaxis, me falto escribir eso

Comment: Tienes cierta reputación por lo que deberias saber que *me marca un error* no es util, debes colocar el mensaje de error completo, muestralo por favor.

Comment: Soy nuevo en c++, y cuando esta compilando me subraya esta parte void main(){, pero como tal no muestra un mensaje de error, debe ser de sintaxis, me falto aclarar eso.

Comment: Entonces coloca una imagen del error :)

Comment: Y las sugerencias que te digo no solo son validas para preguntas relativas a C++ sino a cualquier pregunta en SO, por favor lee [ask] ;)

Comment: Lo tendré en cuenta gracias, pero ya solucione mi problema :)

Comment: Si algunas de las respuestas fue util para resolver tu problema entonces marcarla como correcta, si en cambio fue otro método por favor publicalo como respuesta y marcala como correcta

Comment: Existe una pregunta conceptual sobre este tema , en [Por qué es considerado una mala práctica utilizar variables globales?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/29177/por-qu%C3%A9-es-considerado-una-mala-pr%C3%A1ctica-utilizar-variables-globales)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que la función `main` siempre es de tipo `int` y debe retornar un número.

```
#include<cmath>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int number=3;

int main(){
    cout << number << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

¿Qué es lo que quieres lograr al utilizar una variable global? No es recomendable utilizar variables globales y tal vez te interesa pasarla por referencia a tus funciones. Por ejemplo:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void suma(int &n);

int main(){
  int numero = 0;
  suma(numero);
  cout << numero << '\n';
  suma(numero);
  cout << numero << '\n';
}

void suma(int &n){
 n = n + 10;
}
```

Comment: ¿por qué no son recomendables las variables globales?

Comment: La razón principal por la cual las variables globales son peligrosas se debe a que sus valores pueden ser cambiados por cualquier función que se llame, y no hay una manera fácil para que el programador sepa que esto sucederá. te recomiendo leer esto : http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/4-2a-why-global-variables-are-evil/ y https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484635/are-global-variables-bad

Comment: @Simon mi pregunta va en el sentido que cuando se afirma algo no solo basta la afirmación sino que se debe indicar los motivos en la respuesta

Comment: el motivo es sencillamente el control de las variables por ejemplo si existe otra variable  similar en otra class de c++ y choca con esta puede sobre escribirla y el programador nunca sabria que pasa esto, es como en java o php el limite de las variable

Comment: @Simon como recalco conozco la razon de ello, pero mi cuestion va que akko mejore su pregunta explicando el motivo de esa frase o señalando la literatura que lo sustenta.

Comment: ah ok ups , ps esperemos que el usuario la edite y explique

Answer (score 7):

Tu comprensión de las variables globales es correcto.

#### Tu error.

Tu problema no son las variables globales. Como ya han señalado otros usuarios tu función `main` es incorrecta; es incorrecta porque **debe** devolver `int`. El motivo de esta obligatoriedad es porque (tal y como dice el [estándar del lenguaje C++](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf)) de lo contrario tu programa será incorrecto, te lo muestro directamente extraído del estándar (traducción y resaltado míos):

> #### 3.6.1.2 Función `main`
>
> Las implementaciones no deben predefinir `main`. Esta función no debe ser sobrecargada. **Debe declararse con un retorno de tipo `int`**, pero en caso contrario su tipo es definido por implementación. Las implementaciones deben permitir:
>
> 1. Una función `()` **devolviendo `int`** y
> 2. Una función de `(int, puntero a puntero a char)` **devolviendo `int`**

Así que tu error de sintaxis es porque tu función `main` no sigue el estándar. Apuesto a que incluso el error que te muestra el compilador te está diciendo que dicha función debe devolver `int`.

#### Respecto las variables globales.

Intenta no usar [variables globales](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad):

- **Carecen de localidad**: El código es más fácil de comprender cuando su ámbito es limitado. Las variables globales pueden ser leídas o modificadas desde cualquier parte del programa, esto hace difícil razonar sobre su uso o recordar todos los puntos en que se usan.
- **Carecen de control de acceso o verificación de restricciones**: Una variable global puede ser leída o escrita desde cualquier parte del programa, varias reglas acerca de su uso pueden ser olvidadas o violadas.
- **Problemas de concurrencia**: Si las variables globales pueden ser accedidas desde varios hilos, es necesario sincronizarlas. Cuando se trabaja con módulos dinámicamente enlazados que usan variables globales, el sistema resultante puede no ser seguro incluso cuando los módulos lo sean de manera independiente.
- **Contaminación del espacio de nombres**: Las variables globales están en todos los contextos. Puedes acabar usando una variable global cuando creías estar usando una local ¡o viceversa! (ya sea por desconocimiento, escribir mal el nombre u olvidarte de crear la variable local). Además, si enlazas módulos con variables globales cuyo nombre sea igual, si tienes suerte, tendrás errores de enlazado... si no tienes suerte el enlazador considerará las variables como la misma incluso aunque no fuese tu intención.
- **Más problemas en el enlace (en Inglés)**: He traducido los puntos que creía que eran más relevantes para tu problema.

Comment: Gracias por la rta, si no es recomendable manejar variables globales, entonces que puedo hacer para manejar una variable con varias funciones?

Comment: Esa es una pregunta muy compleja que no es adecuado responder en un comentario, te aconsejo preparar un caso práctico y un código de ejemplo y elaborar una pregunta alrededor de ello.

Comment: Vale gracias, después hare una pregunta.

Answer (score 4):

Veo dos errores aquí: primero, usas `void main(){` donde debería ser `int main`, ¿por qué? porque vas a devolver un entero. El segundo error que veo es que no lo devuelves, o sea, no agregas un return, como en el siguiente código:

```
#include<cmath>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int number=3;

int main(){

  cout<<number;
   return 0;
}
```

Te recomiendo leer esto :[input_output en c++](http://www-numi.fnal.gov/offline_software/srt_public_context/WebDocs/Companion/cxx_crib/input_output.html)
y [variables locales y globales en c++](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1708657&seqNum=3)
[int-main-vs-void-main-in-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9356510/int-main-vs-void-main-in-c)

Comment: por favor mejora tu redacción, no coloques `?` innecesariamente, una respuesta de calidad debe ser correctamente escrita.

Comment: ok gracias por tu sugerencia la tomare en cuenta

Comment: Simon te recomiendo devolver 0, por convencion el retorno de 0 indica que el programa se ejecuto sin problemas, otro valor indicara que hubo un problema.

Comment: ya lo agrege en el codigo

Comment: A mi me preocupa el `return  number;`, eso es incorrecto :)

Comment: ah perdon :) ya la edite la respuesta :)

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80582/discussion-between-simon-and-eyllanesc).

Comment: Solución rápida puede oler a solución apestosa, cuidese de ello, recuerde que en SO no solo deben de servir al que pregunta sino a los futuros lectores.

Comment: lose :) perdon intentare mejorar las respuesta.

Comment: No es obligatorio incluir el `return 0;`. Revisa este enlace: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/139624/63114

Comment: te recomiendo leer esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138649/why-is-return-0-optional y http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/24461/

Answer (score 1):

Prueba esta **sintaxis**, ¿por qué? porque es un estandar en C/C++, un `int main` y su respectivo `return 0`.

```
#include<cmath>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int number=3;

int main(){
    cout<<number;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Una respuesta de calidad no solo puede decir *prueba esto*, que quiere decir *quizas funcione*, debes explicar porque lo que propones es la solución y cual es la causa del problema, lee por favor [answer] y mejora tu respuesta

Comment: dijo lo mismo debes mejorar tu respuesta

Comment: No *es una buena práctica, un `int main`*, es la única práctica posible. El estándar de C++ establece que la función `main` **debe** devolver `int`. A @DDR no le funcionaba porque su programa era erróneo precisamente por no seguir las normas del estándar.

Comment: -1 porque no se trata de buenas prácticas. El asunto es seguir lo que indica el estándar de C++.

Comment: Ya corregí mi publicación