# Pierdo 2 registros al abrir un ofstream C++

Tags: c++, array, archivo, estructuras-de-datos

tengo un problema serio que no puedo solucionar.
No entiendo por que, al abrir un archivo de salida estoy perdiendo 2 posiciones de un vector de registros que no toco en ninguna parte.

El problema, creo yo, ojala puedan corregirme, se encuentra en el modulo ListadoHR(). Al compilar, en el archivo de salida estoy perdiendo la posicion 0 y 1 de "tabla", pero todo el resto del vector se conserva bien...

> Archivo de salida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto el codigo:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream.h>
#include <iomanip.h>

using namespace std;

typedef char str20[21];
typedef unsigned short ushort;
const ushort N = 15;

struct t_Archivo{
    float x,
          y;
    str20 direccion;
};
struct t_TblInterna{
    float dist; ///distancia al inicio
    float x,
          y;
    str20 direccion;
};

ushort i = 0;

bool LeerCoord(ifstream &arch, t_Archivo rArch[]);
void ProcDatosEnTbl(t_Archivo *rArch, t_TblInterna &elemTabla);
void HojaRuta(t_TblInterna *tabla);
float Distancia(float x2, float x1, float y2, float y1);
void ListadoHR(t_TblInterna tabla[]);
void OrdxBur(t_TblInterna *nomTbl, ushort cardinalidad);
void IntCmb(t_TblInterna &e1, t_TblInterna &e2);



int main(){

    ifstream NLArchivo;

    t_Archivo regArchivo[N];
    t_TblInterna regTbl[N];
    NLArchivo.open("CoordenadasXY.txt");

    while( LeerCoord(NLArchivo, regArchivo) )
        ProcDatosEnTbl(regArchivo,regTbl[i++]);
    cout << "(MAIN 0) " << regTbl[0].direccion << endl;///
    HojaRuta(regTbl);
    cout << "(MAIN 1) " << regTbl[0].direccion << endl;///
    ListadoHR(regTbl);
    NLArchivo.close();
    cout << "\n\n(MAIN 2) " << regTbl[0].direccion << endl;///

    return 0;
}
float Distancia(float x2, float x1, float y2, float y1){
    float dist = sqrt( pow(x2 - x1,2) + pow (y2 - y1,2));
    return dist;
}
void IntCmb(t_TblInterna &e1, t_TblInterna &e2){
    t_TblInterna aux;
    aux = e1;
    e1 = e2;
    e2 = aux;
}
bool LeerCoord(ifstream &arch,t_Archivo rArch[]){
    bool estado = false;
    if(i<N)
    {
        string leido = "";
        arch >> leido;
        rArch[i].x = atof(leido.c_str());
        cout << "Leido: i="<< i << " " << rArch[i].x << " "; ///
        arch >> leido;
        rArch[i].y = atof(leido.c_str());
        cout << rArch[i].y << " "; ///
        arch >>  leido;
        strcpy(rArch[i].direccion, leido.c_str());
        cout << rArch[i].direccion << "." << endl; ///
        estado = true;
    }
    return estado;
}
void ProcDatosEnTbl(t_Archivo *rArch, t_TblInterna &elemTabla){
        cout << "estoy en i = " << i << endl; ///
        elemTabla.x = rArch[i-1].x;
        elemTabla.y = rArch[i-1].y;
        elemTabla.dist = 0;
        strcpy(elemTabla.direccion, rArch[i-1].direccion);
        elemTabla.direccion[21] = '\0';///
        cout << "COPIE /"<< elemTabla.direccion << "/" << endl; ///

        ///cargo todas las direcciones dentro del registro
        ///de tabla interna + X e Y de c/pos
}

void ListadoHR(t_TblInterna tabla[]){

    cout << "\ndoble chk 0 " << tabla[0].direccion << endl; ///
    cout << "\ndoble chk 1 " << tabla[1].direccion << endl; /// hasta aqui perfecto
    ofstream salida ("ListadoHjRt.txt",ios::out);
/// AQUI YA SE LLENO DE BASURA LA POS. 0 Y 1!!!!

    salida << "\t\tListado Hoja de rutas" << endl;
    salida << left << setw(25) << "#Ord.Domicilio" <<
              right<< setw(25) << "Dist. al Destino" << endl;
    for(short ind = 0; ind < N; ind ++){

        salida  << left << setw(4) << (ind+1) << tabla[ind].direccion
                << "(" << setprecision(2) << fixed << tabla[ind].dist
                << ")" << setw(10) << " " <<
                right << setw(10) << tabla[ind].dist << endl;
    }
    salida.close();
    cout << "hasta aca llego" << endl; ///
}

void HojaRuta(t_TblInterna *tabla){
    for(short cont = 1; cont < N ; cont++ ){
        float distanciaAlInicio;
        distanciaAlInicio = Distancia(tabla[cont].x,tabla[0].x,
                                      tabla[cont].y,tabla[0].y);
        tabla[cont].dist = distanciaAlInicio;
    }
    //una vez sacadas todas las distancias, ordeno
    OrdxBur(tabla,N);
    for(short t = 0; t< N ;t++)
    {
        cout << "debug pos " << t << ": " << tabla[t].direccion;
    }
}

void OrdxBur(t_TblInterna *nomTbl, ushort cardinalidad){
    ushort x, y; //contadores
    for(x = 1;x < cardinalidad ; x++){
        for(y = 1; y < cardinalidad - x ; y++)
            if(nomTbl[y].dist > nomTbl[y+1].dist)
                IntCmb(nomTbl[y],nomTbl[y+1]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Tu código es complicado de seguir y complejo en exceso, es normal que no encuentres el error. En este tipo de problemas, en general, el problema no suele estar en el mostrado de datos (en tu caso `ListadoHR`) si no en la lectura (en tu caso `LeerCord`) o en el guardado. Tu código no es una excepción: estás procesando mal los datos que lees, en la función `ProcDatosEnTbl`:

```
void ProcDatosEnTbl(t_Archivo *rArch, t_TblInterna &elemTabla){
    cout << "estoy en i = " << i << endl; ///
    elemTabla.x = rArch[i-1].x; // ¿Por qué restar una posición
    elemTabla.y = rArch[i-1].y; // en este array?
    elemTabla.dist = 0;
    strcpy(elemTabla.direccion, rArch[i-1].direccion);
    elemTabla.direccion[21] = '\0';///
    cout << "COPIE /"<< elemTabla.direccion << "/" << endl; ///
}
```

Cuando la variable global `i` es `0` accedes al registro `-1` y en consecuencia rellenas en la tabla valores inesperados.

#### Otras cosas a tener en cuenta.

- Las cabeceras `<iostream.h>` e `<iomanip.h>` no existen, las cabeceras estándar de C++ no tienen extensión, seguramente querías incluir `<iostream>` e `<iomanip>`.
- La cabecera `<math.h>` es de C, `<cmath>` es la versión adaptada  C++ y es la que deberías usar, lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/48268/2742) para conocer más detalles.
- Evita usar `using namespace std`, y si lo usas hazlo en el ámbito más pequeño posible, no en el ámbito global, lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/460/2742) para conocer más detalles.
- Evita usar variables globales, lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/29177/2742) para conocer más detalles, también puedes leer [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/183489/2742) para detalles adicionales.
- Abandona el uso de formaciones<sup>1</sup>, C++ ofrece herramientas mucho más flexibles, menos propensas a errores y más fáciles de usar como [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string) y [`std::list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list).
- Abandona el uso de punteros en crudo, C++ ofrece utilidades mucho más seguras como las referencias.
- No uses `std::endl` a no ser que sea estrictamente necesario, lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/47839/2742) para conocer más detalles.

---

1. También conocidas como *arreglos* o en Inglés *arrays*.