# Llamar función con estructura en C++

Tags: c++, funciones, estructuras

Estoy realizando un menú con varios programas en el `switch` llamo al `case` y en el `case` la función, llego el tema de estructuras pero no me envía el dato ni de sexo, ni de club.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<string.h>

using namespace std;

//prototipo de la funcion 
int programa1();

int main (){

int opc;
do{
system("COLOR 1E");

    cout<<"\t Bienvenido al Menu de Programas: "<<endl;
        cout<<"1.-Programa:  "<<endl;
         cout<<"Opcion: ";
    cin>>opc;
    system("cls");
  switch(opc){
        case 1:
        system ("color 08"); 
        programa1();

        break;  
    }    
  }while (opc !=30);
  return 0;

 }

struct Corredor{
char nombre[20];
int edad ;
char sexo[10];
char club[21];
}c1;


int programa1(){
char categoria[20];

cout<<"Nombre: "; 
cin.ignore(20,'\n');
cin.getline(c1.nombre,20,'\n');
cout<<"Edad: "; 
cin>>c1.edad;
fflush(stdin);
cout<<"Sexo: "; 
cin.ignore(10,'\n');
cin.getline(c1.sexo,10,'\n');
cout<<"Club: "; 
cin.ignore(20,'\n');
cin.getline(c1.club,20,'\n');


if(c1.edad <= 18){
    strcpy(categoria,"Juvenil");
}   
else if(c1.edad <= 40){
    strcpy(categoria,"Senior");
}
else{
    strcpy(categoria,"Veterano");
}

cout<<"\n\nMostrando Datos"<<endl;
cout<<"Nombre: "<<c1.nombre<<endl;
cout<<"Edad: "<<c1.edad<<endl;
cout<<"Sexo: "<<c1.sexo<<endl;
cout<<"Club: "<<c1.club<<endl;
cout<<"Categoria: "<<categoria<<endl;

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿Porqué haces `cin.ignore()`?¿?¿?

Comment: Si estas en c++ porque usas estructuras?? no es mejor una clase???

Comment: El cin.ignore() sirve para borrar el buffer del cin.getline si no le toma automaticamente una variable.

Comment: @abrahamhs es indiferente `struct` o `class`, sólo cambia la visibilidad por defecto de los datos contenidos.

Answer (score 1):

Tu código es confuso y difícil de seguir, además de contar con múltiples fallos de concepto. En primer lugar, señalaré que estás programando en C++ por lo tanto deberías seguir las premisas, costumbres y constructos de C++:

- Las cabeceras `<stdlib.h>`, `<math.h>`, `<stdio.h>`, `<time.h>` y `<string.h>` son de C, no de C++, si realmente necesitas usarlas (que no las necesitas) debes usar los equivalentes de C++: `<cstdlib>`, `<cmath>`, `<cstdio>`, `<ctime>`, `<cstring>`. Consulta [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/48268/2742) para saber por qué.
- La cabecera `<conio.h>` ni siquiera es estándar C y no existe en C++, consulta [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/122350/2742) para saber por qué.
- La manera de trabajar con cadenas de caracteres en C++ es usando objetos de tipo [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string) (accesibles tras incluir la cabecera `<string>`) no con formaciones<sup>1</sup> de caracteres.
- No se aconseja el uso de `using namespace std;` en el ámbito global, si fuese necesario usarlo (no suele serlo) debe usarse en el ámbito más pequeño posible. Consulta [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/460/2742) para saber por qué.
- No suele ser necesario usar `std::endl`, es más eficiente usar un salto de línea explícito `\n`, consulta [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/47839/2742) para saber por qué.
- Evita las variables globales, consulta [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/183489/2742) para saber por qué.
- Deja a tus variables respirar, apretujar el código para que ocupe menos tenía sentido en los 80 cuando los monitores mostraban 80 caracteres por línea y 20 líneas por pantalla; hoy día no tiene sentido.

Teniendo en cuenta todas estas correcciones tu código podría quedar así:

#### Propuesta.

```
// Usando std::string, no char[]
struct Corredor {
    std::string nombre;
    int edad = 0;
    std::string sexo;
    std::string club;
};

// No utilizas el retorno de la función, así que no necesita retorno
void programa1() {
    std::string categoria;

    Corredor c1; // Sin variables globales.

    // El código separado es más legible
    std::cout << "Nombre: "; 
    std::cin >> c1.nombre;

    std::cout << "Edad: "; 
    std::cin >> c1.edad;

    std::cout << "Sexo: "; 
    std::cin >> c1.sexo;

    std::cout << "Club: "; 
    std::cin >> c1.club;

    // No hay necesidad de strcpy
    if (c1.edad <= 18) {
        categoria = "Juvenil";
    }
    else if(c1.edad <= 40) {
        categoria = "Senior";
    }
    else {
        categoria = "Veterano";
    }

    // Por qué llamar varias veces a std::cout pudiendo llamarlo sólo una?
    std::cout << "\n\nMostrando Datos"
                 "\nNombre: " << c1.nombre <<
                 "\nEdad: " << c1.edad <<
                 "\nSexo: " << c1.sexo <<
                 "\nClub: " << c1.club <<
                 "\nCategoria: " << categoria << '\n';
}
```

Si cambias tus formaciones<sup>1</sup> de caracteres a `std::string` como en la propuesta, el programa funcionará como esperas.

---

1. También conocidas como *arreglos* o en inglés *arrays*.

Answer (score -2):

Qué tal, el problema es que declaraste las variables sexo y club  de la estructura como arreglo de `char`, de esta manera no las puedes leer de manera "directa" con `cin`.

Para resolverlo, declara las variables de esta manera:

`char* sexo;`

`char* club;`

De esta manera las podrás leer sin problema con `cin`.

Comment: Ya lo intente no me pasa de nombre.

Comment: para la variable nombre es el mismo caso, declárala como char*

Comment: Correcto lo hice de esa forma se queda en la variable nombre: ingreso el nombre y el programa se termina.

struct Corredor{
char* nombre;
int edad ;
char* sexo;
char* club;
}c1;

Comment: Esta respuesta es incorrecta. Declarando variables miembro como punteros a carácter y leyendo sobre los mismos mediante `std::cin` se provocará una [violación de segmento](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Violación_de_acceso).