# Programa para captar valores y mostrar cuantos ceros hay?

Tags: c++

Necesito captar un valor de la cantidad de veces que almacenaras números, pero no consigo hacer que me imprima la cantidad de veces que almacene un 0 en uno o n valores.

Tengo esto de codigo

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int i,c;
int num[100];
int main()
{
    int n;
    cout << "Dame el valor de n: "; 
    cin >> n;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << "Dame numero: "; cin >> num[i];
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {

        do {

            int ceros = 1,almacenaceros=0;

            almacenaceros = +1;

            cout << "hay " << almacenaceros << "ceros" << endl;


        } while (num[i] == 0);

    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Si el contador de ceros se declara dentro de cada iteración dificilmente va a funcionar como esperas:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) { // Inicio del bucle

    do {

        int ceros = 1,almacenaceros=0; // Declaras la variable almacenaceros

        almacenaceros = +1;

        cout << "hay " << almacenaceros << "ceros" << endl;


    } while (num[i] == 0); // la variable muere y su valor se pierde
    //           ^ Nota que en el bucle do-while, el valor de i no cambia --> recursión infinita si num[i]==0

}
```

Tienes que garantizar que la variable va a estar **viva** durante todo el tiempo que la necesites. En este caso, la variable tendrá que existir ininterrumpidamente desde que empiezas a buscar números hasta que muestras el resultado final:

```
int almacenaceros = 0; // Variable declarada fuera del bucle
                       // Seguirá viva al finalizar dicho bucle
for( int i=0; i<n; i++ )
{
  if( num[i] == 0 )
    almacenaceros++; // Modificamos su valor cuantas veces necesitemos
}

std::cout << "hay " << almacenaceros << " ceros\n"; // Mostramos el valor final
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrías realizar algo como esto:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i; int num[100]; int n; int almacenaceros=0;
    cout << "Dame el valor de n: "; 
    cin >> n;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << "Dame numero: ";
        cin >> num[i];
        //Luego de leer el numero se verifica si es el numero cero
        //y se incrementa el contador de ceros.
        if (num[i] == 0) {
            almacenaceros += 1;
        };
    }
    //Al finalizar el for imprimes la cantidad de ceros ingresados.
    cout << "hay " << almacenaceros << " ceros" << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Realizo la comparación dentro del mismo `for` donde se lee el numero que ingrese el usuario porque así se evita realizar otro `for`. Y el `do..while` no es necesario; es suficiente usar el `if` para realizar la comparación.

Corriendo: https://onlinegdb.com/B1I8qP4dV

Answer (score 1):

Si sólo necesitas contar los `0` que se introducen, no necesitarás siquiera guardar los datos:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    int cantidad, ceros;
    cout << "Dame la cantidad: "; 
    cin >> cantidad;

    for (int indice = 0; indice < cantidad; ++indice) {
        int numero;
        cout << "Dame numero: ";
        cin >> numero;
        ceros += numero ? 0 : 1;
    }

    cout << "hay " << ceros<< " ceros\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Los cambios que he hecho a tu código son los siguientes:

- La cláusula `using namespace std` está dentro de `main`. Usar esta cláusula no es obligatorio (sólo es una ayuda a la escritura de código), si realmente quieres usarla, lo aconsejable es usarla en el ámbito más pequeño posible. Lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/460/2742) para saber más.
- He cambiado los nombres de las variables. Es muy importante que los nombres de las variables sean autoexplcativos y claros, con el nombre adecuado puedes transmitir a otras personas (incluído tu "yo futuro") la intencionalidad y propósito del código.
- He movido la variable de control del primer bucle `for` del ámbito global al ámbito del bucle. Se considera una buena práctica que el ámbito de las variables sea el más pequeño posible y que su declaración y uso esté lo más próximo posible. El ámbito global es el más grande posible, por lo que no seguías esta premisa. Lee [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/183489/2742) para tener más detalles sobre variables globales.
- He cambiado el post-incremento a pre-incremento, lee [este artículo](https://vitaminacpp.wordpress.com/2012/04/10/leyenda-pre-y-post-incremento/) para saber por qué es una mejora.

Respecto a la manera de contar ceros:

```
ceros += numero ? 0 : 1;
```

Estoy usando dos *trucos* de C++:

- Conversión implícita de número a valor booleano. En C++ (y C) los valores numéricos se convierten implícitamente a valores booleanos (verdadero/falso) cuando se usan en el contexto de una expresión booleana. La conversión se realiza con estas sencillas normas:

  - Si el valor es `0`, la expresión booleana es `false`.
  - Si el valor es `1`, la expresión booleana es `true`.
- Operador ternario. El operador ternario es una instrucción `if` convertida a expresión. Su formato es: *condición* `?` *valor verdadero* `:` *valor falso*. Si *condición* se cumple el valor de la expresión será *valor verdadero*, en caso contrario será *valor falso*.

Con estos trucos, la expresión que cuenta los ceros, sumará `0` al contador cuando `numero` sea cualquier valor diferente de `0` y sumará `1` al contador cuando el valor sea cero.