# Como hago una variable del mismo tipo de la clase en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, lista, clase, java-8, class

Quiero hacer una lista simple enlazada con javascript y para eso, necesito hacer una variable del mismo tipo de la clase, en Java lo hacia así:

```
class Nodo{

    public char datoNodo; 

    public Nodo sgte;


 public Nodo(char dato){
  this.dato=dato;
 } 


}
```

Ya que en javascript no se puede especificar el tipo de variable, solo se especifica con 'var'.

Answer (score 1):

Hola espero ser de ayuda.

javascript no es altamente tipado por lo que no al creear la variable no nesesitas definirlo con su tipo, por que con var te deveria bastar,

pero te recomiendo usar let es la forma moderna de definir variables en javascipt

saludos

Comment: primero estas equivocado; aunque javascript no es altamente tipado si posee varios tipos de datos, segundo no es que let sea la forma moderna de declarar variables es que var y let tienen distinto alcance

Comment: deberias leer esto para dejar usar variables globales. [enlace]https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/29177/por-qu%C3%A9-es-considerado-una-mala-pr%C3%A1ctica-utilizar-variables-globales[/enlace]  y con lo de atipado me exprese mal quise decir ***no es altamente tipado*** gracias por la correcion saludos

Comment: se la diferencia entre var y let pero afirmar que es algo moderno es falso; es una concepción y tratamiento diferente del alcance de las variables

Comment: el uso de let hace unos años atras no se aplicaba por lo que su uso actual lo hacen moderno, dado que es en la actualida tiempo presente y no pasado digase de moderno ***Acorde con el tiempo actual,avanzado en sus características,ideas,usos o costumbres:*** saludos

Answer (score 1):

Puedes escribir algo como esto:

```
class Nodo{

        constructor(Nodo, dato){
            this.Nodo= Nodo;
            this.dato=dato;
        }

    }

let my_nodo1 = new Nodo();
let my_nodo2 = new Nodo(my_nodo1,"Hola, usuario");
console.log(my_nodo2.dato);
```

Es equivalente a lo que haces con Java.