# Comparar una variable y un arreglo en C

Tags: c

Estoy elaborando un programa el cual sirviera como una base para guardar una agenda para personas pero la linea ***if(bcod==cod[h])*** parece no trabajar correctamente, como podria solucionar o elaborarlo de una manera alternativa?
Al correr el programa todo va bien hasta ese punto me dice que no existe, estoy utilizando DevC++ como IDE. Ademas de que aveces me aparecia a veces este codigo de error en esa linea "*ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer* ".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int n,h,a,d,comp;
int cod[100];
char nom[40][100];
int tel[100];
char email[15][100];
int bcod;

int main(){

    system("cls");
    printf("Agenda de tu empresa\n\n");
    printf("Ingrese el número de contactos que deseas ingresar: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for(h=0; h+1<=n; h++){

        printf("\nIngresando contacto #%d\n", h+1);

        printf("\n> Ingrese Codigo: ");
        scanf("%d", &cod[h]);
        printf("\n> Ingrese Nombre: ");
        scanf("%s", &nom[h]);
        printf("\n> Ingrese Telefono: ");
        scanf("%d", &tel[h]);
        printf("\n> Ingrese Correo: ");
        scanf("%s", &email[h]);
            system("cls");
    }
    system("cls");

    for(h=0; h+1<=n; h++){

        printf("\nGuardando Contacto #%d\n", h+1);
        printf("Su Codigo es: %d\n", cod[h]);
        printf("Su Nombre es: %s\n", nom[h]);
        printf("Su Numero es: %d\n", tel[h]);
        printf("Su E-mail es: %s\n", email[h]);
        Sleep(3250);
        }
     system("cls");

     printf("Menu de busqueda");
     printf("Escriba el codigo de la persona a buscar: ");
     scanf("%d", &bcod); 

     if(bcod==cod[h]){
     printf("Contacto #%d\n", h+1);
     printf("El Codigo es: %d", cod[h]);
     printf("Su Nombre es: %s", nom[h]);
     printf("Su Numero es: %d", tel[h]);
     printf("Su E-mail es: %s", email[h]);
     }
     else{
     printf("No existe");
     }
getch();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> > Estoy elaborando un programa el cual sirviera como una base para guardar una agenda para personas pero la linea if(bcod==cod[h]) parece no trabajar correctamente...

El error se debe porqué no estás haciendo la búsqueda de información a través de un bucle (`for`, `while` o `do-while`).

Analicemos esta condición:

```
if(bcod==cod[h])
```

La variable `h` anteriormente se la usó en un bucle y está claro que se quedó con el valor que tenga la variable `n`. Por ejemplo, imagínate que la variable `n` tiene guardado un `10`, esto quiere decir que el arreglo `cod` tendrá `10` códigos de personas, el resto de espacio valdrán `0` (como declaraste el arreglo `cod` como global, el compilador inicializa cada elemento del arreglo a `0`).

Así que cuando esta condición se evalue:

```
bcod == cod[h]
```

Dará como resultado un `false`, porqué como `h` tiene el mismo valor que `n` (un `10`), estaríamos accediendo a la posición `10` del arreglo `cod`, dando como resultado un `0` y la única forma para que la condición se cumpla, es que la variable `bcod` tenga almacenado un `0`, de lo contrario, la restricción siempre arrojará un `false` y esa es la razón del porqué te imprime el mensaje: `No existe`.

**Solución:** Debes recorrer cada elemento del arreglo `cod` a través de un bucle y compararlo con el valor que tenga almacenado la variable `bcod`.

```
for(h = 0; h < n; h++)
{
    if(bcod==cod[h])
    {
        printf("Contacto #%d\n", h+1);
        printf("El Codigo es: %d", cod[h]);
        printf("Su Nombre es: %s", nom[h]);
        printf("Su Numero es: %d", tel[h]);
        printf("Su E-mail es: %s", email[h]);
        break; //Rompemos el ciclo for.
    }
}
if(h == n)
    printf("No existe");
```

> > ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer

El error se debe porqué estás comparando una dirección de memoria con un número entero.

Ejemplo:

```
if(bcod == cod)
```

El código de arriba dará un posible error de compilación (dependería del compilador) porqué no tiene ningún sentido comparar el contenido del puntero `cod` con la variable `bcod`.

**Observaciones:**

**1.** Al principio tienes declarado estos arreglos:

```
int cod[100];
char nom[40][100];
int tel[100];
char email[15][100];
```

Sin embargo, no tienen el mismo tamaño. En la matriz `nom` tiene como capacidad máxima para almacenar 40 nombres (que representa el número de filas) de personas y en `cod` se tiene como tamaño máximo un `100`, es decir, esto puede ocasionar un [desbordamiento de búfer](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desbordamiento_de_b%C3%BAfer). Por ejemplo, si la variable `n` llegara a tener un valor de `95`, estarás desbordando la matriz `nom`, porqué en su primera dimensión solo acepta índices de `0` a `39`.

El [desbordamiento de búfer](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desbordamiento_de_b%C3%BAfer) es un error que te pueda costar horas en solucionarlo y más aún cuando sobreescribes algún espacio de memoria del propio programa. Otra consecuencia sería si se llegara a sobreescribir un registro que al programa no le pertenece, en este caso el programa si dejaría de funcionar, debido a que, ocurriría un [fallo de segmentación](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Violaci%C3%B3n_de_acceso).

La **solución** sería cambiar el número de filas a `100` de las matrices `nom` y `email`.

```
#define MAX_PERSONAS   100
int cod[MAX_PERSONAS];
char nom[MAX_PERSONAS][100];
int tel[MAX_PERSONAS];
char email[MAX_PERSONAS][100];
```

**2.** Al momento de pedir al usuario que ingrese el número de contactos, estás dando la oportunidad de que ocurra un posible [desbordamiento de búfer](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desbordamiento_de_b%C3%BAfer). Anteriormente habíamos definido que la capacidad máxima de cada arreglo sería de `100`, sin embargo, si el usuario llegara a ingresar un `110`, se estaría pasando del tamaño máximo, debido a que, los arreglos `nom`, `email`, `cod`, solo aceptarán índices de `0` a `99`.

La **solución** sería establecer una restricción al usuario para que solo pueda ingresar como máximo 100 contactos.

```
do{
    printf("Ingrese el número de contactos que deseas ingresar: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    if(n < 1 || n > 100)
    {
        printf("Error: Solo se permite ingresar de 1 a 100 contactos\n\n");
        continue;
    }
    break;
}while(1);
```

**3.** No deberías usar variables globales de forma innecesaria (para más información: [¿Por qué es considerado una mala práctica utilizar variables globales?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/29177/por-qu%C3%A9-es-considerado-una-mala-pr%C3%A1ctica-utilizar-variables-globales)), esto se debe porqué hace que la depuración del código sea más complicada de ver, ya que no se sabe en que momento va a cambiar el valor de la variable. En su reemplazo, puedes hacer uso de variables locales.

**4.** Si vas a usar la función [scanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) para leer una cadena hasta encontrar un espacio, por lo menos debes anteponer en el especificador, el tamaño máximo de caracteres que podrá leer la función `scanf` en el búfer del teclado, de lo contrario, habrá [desbordamiento de búfer](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desbordamiento_de_b%C3%BAfer).

```
for(h=0; h+1<=n; h++)
{
   printf("\nIngresando contacto #%d\n", h+1);
   printf("\n> Ingrese Codigo: ");
   scanf("%d", &cod[h]);
   printf("\n> Ingrese Nombre: ");
   scanf("%99s", &nom[h]);
   printf("\n> Ingrese Telefono: ");
   scanf("%d", &tel[h]);
   printf("\n> Ingrese Correo: ");
   scanf("%99s", &email[h]);
   system("cls");
}
```

Se agrega `99` para que la función `scanf` pueda leer hasta 99 caracteres, debido a que, se debe dejar un espacio para el caracter nulo.

Tu programa quedaría de esta forma teniendo en cuenta las cuatro observaciones que se mencionaron anteriormente:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#define MAX_PERSONAS 100

int main()
{
    int n,h,a,d,comp;
    int cod[MAX_PERSONAS];
    char nom[MAX_PERSONAS][100];
    int tel[MAX_PERSONAS];
    char email[MAX_PERSONAS][100];
    int bcod;
    system("cls");
    printf("Agenda de tu empresa\n\n");
    printf("Ingrese el número de contactos que deseas ingresar: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    do{
        printf("Ingrese el número de contactos que deseas ingresar: ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        if(n < 1 || n > 100)
        {
            printf("Error: Solo se permite hasta 100 contactos\n\n");
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }while(1);
    for(h=0; h+1<=n; h++)
    {
        printf("\nIngresando contacto #%d\n", h+1);
        printf("\n> Ingrese Codigo: ");
        scanf("%d", &cod[h]);
        printf("\n> Ingrese Nombre: ");
        scanf("%99s", &nom[h]);
        printf("\n> Ingrese Telefono: ");
        scanf("%d", &tel[h]);
        printf("\n> Ingrese Correo: ");
        scanf("%99s", &email[h]);
        system("cls");
    }
    system("cls");
    for(h=0; h+1<=n; h++)
    {
        printf("\nGuardando Contacto #%d\n", h+1);
        printf("Su Codigo es: %d\n", cod[h]);
        printf("Su Nombre es: %s\n", nom[h]);
        printf("Su Numero es: %d\n", tel[h]);
        printf("Su E-mail es: %s\n", email[h]);
        Sleep(3250);
    }
     system("cls");
     printf("Menu de busqueda");
     printf("Escriba el codigo de la persona a buscar: ");
     scanf("%d", &bcod); 
    //Recorremos cada elemento del arreglo
    for(h = 0; h < n; h++)
    {
        if(bcod==cod[h])
        {
            printf("Contacto #%d\n", h+1);
            printf("El Codigo es: %d", cod[h]);
            printf("Su Nombre es: %s", nom[h]);
            printf("Su Numero es: %d", tel[h]);
            printf("Su E-mail es: %s", email[h]);
            break;
        }
    }
    if(h == n)
        printf("No existe");
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

**Recomendación:** Podrías hacer uso de una [lista enlazada](https://gist.github.com/ArgiesDario/da409828e81ef441186268b8ee3acd5f) para no limitar el registro de contactos.