# ¿Como usar datos usados en def que se mantengan a lo largo del codigo?

Tags: python, python-3.x, funciones

Estoy trabajando en un menú donde se tiene que cargar un diccionario como función, pero como se trabaja con otras funciones al momento de llamarlas se pierde la información y no la guarda. Es un proyecto final, me encantaría que me explicaran porque no funciona mas que resolver el problema.

Los problemas que tengo:

- El contador me lo da como error.
- Debería cargarse el diccionario una sola vez y no lo hace

El archivo que se usa:

```
1,casa,2,house,3,maison

2,table,3,table,1,mesa

3,fille,2,daughter,1,hija

2,she,1,ella,3,elle
```

El código:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import csv
import time

def cargar ():
  key_dic = {"1": "español", "2": "inglés", "3":"frances"}
  dic = defaultdict(list)
  with open("/content/diccionario.dat") as file:
      for line in file.readlines():
          for palabra in line.strip().split(","):
              if palabra.isnumeric():
                  key = key_dic[palabra]
              else:
                  dic[key].append(palabra)
  print(dic)

contador=0
def no_carga():
  print("No se ha activado el diccionario")  


def es_in ():
  cargar()
  print ("-----------------------------------------")
  busqueda = input("Introduzca la palabra que desea buscar \n")

  if busqueda in diccionario["español"]:
    print ("-----------------------------------------")
    indice=diccionario["español"].index(busqueda)
    print ("Su traduccion al idioma Ingles es: ",diccionario["ingles"][indice])
    print ("-----------------------------------------")
    print ("")

  if busqueda not in diccionario["español"]:
    print("NO SE ENCUENTRA, INTENTA AGAIN")


def in_fr ():
  diccionario ={"español":["casa","mesa","hija","ella"],"ingles":["house","table","daughter","she"],"frances":["maison","table","fille","elle"]}
  print ("-----------------------------------------")
  busqueda = input("Introduzca la palabra que desea buscar \n")

  if busqueda in diccionario["ingles"]:
    indice=diccionario["ingles"].index(busqueda)
    print ("-----------------------------------------")
    print ("Su traduccion al idioma Frances es: ",diccionario["frances"][indice])
    print ("-----------------------------------------")
    print ("")


  if busqueda not in diccionario["ingles"]:
    print("NO SE ENCUENTRA, INTENTA AGAIN")


def menu ():
  
  print ("************************************")
  print("Bienvenido al Diccionario de Ninos")
  print ("************************************")
  print ("1. Cargar Diccionario \n",
          "2. Español – Inglés \n",
          "3. Inglés – Francés \n",
          "4. Buscar Palabras \n",
          "5. Salir")
 
  eleccion = int(input("Presionar opcion de ejecucion: "))
  if eleccion == 1:
    contador=1
    cargar()
    

  elif eleccion == 2:
   if contador==1:
      es_in ()
   else:
    no_carga()

    
  elif eleccion == 3:
    in_fr ()
  

  elif eleccion == 4:
    buscar ()

  elif eleccion == 5:
    exit()
  
  elif eleccion >= 6:
    print("Opcion no valida")

  elif eleccion < 1:
    print("Opcion no valida")

while True:
  try:
    menu()
    time.sleep(2)
  except ValueError:
    print("Opcion no valida")
```

Comment: Necesitas una variable "global" para guardar el diccionario. Podrías hacer que la función cargar devolviera el diccionario cargado, para poder guardarlo en una variable fuera de la función.

Comment: Gracias ahora lo intento

Comment: @PabloLozano lo hice pero me da error diciendo que "diccionario" no esta definido, cuando le pedi a la funcion cargar que lo retorne

Comment: @jgl ¿Te sirve mi respuesta?

Comment: @PabloLozano Ya entendi lo que me querias decir, lo vi hoy en clase XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ¿Como usar datos usados en def que se mantengan a lo largo del codigo?

Para eso existen las variables globales, que por cierto [es una mala práctica](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/29177/por-qu%C3%A9-es-considerado-una-mala-pr%C3%A1ctica-utilizar-variables-globales).

```
bar = "alguna"

def foo():
    global bar

    bar += "cosa"

foo()
```

De no realizar [la declaración global](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement), se obtendría un  error.

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'bar' referenced before assignment
```

Como dije, esto es una mala práctica (ver el enlace de arriba). Entonces, *¿Cuál es la manera "buena"?*

Puedes usar [la declaración return](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement), que le asigna un valor a la evaluación de la función. El valor predeterminado de una función es `None`.

```
def foo():
    var = "alguna"

    return var

def bar(word):
    print(word, "cosa")

word = foo()
bar(word)
```

La función retorna `foo()` un valor y se usa como parámetro de `bar()`. Por lo tanto, el valor de `var` persiste en `bar()`.

```
alguna cosa
```

Otra opción es implementar llamadas dentro de una función a otra función con argumentos.

```
def foo():
    var = "alguna cosa"

    bar(var)

def bar(word):
    print(word)

foo()
```

Se llama a `foo()`, debido a que esta llama a `bar()`. El argumento que se usa se toma en cuenta del scope de `bar()`.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: No entiendo XD, me podrias explicar de otra forma

Comment: acabo de probarlo y lo entendi excelente servicio @Gabitohh

Answer (score 0):

Te estás complicando mucho con la parte de las opciones. Y también complicas más de la cuenta hacer un diccionario de datos desordenado. Puedes trabajar el diccionario en una hoja de cálculo externa con las columnas definidas: Español - Inglés - Francés

**dicionario.csv**

```
casa,house,maison
mesa,table,table
hija,daughter,fille
ella,she,elle
```

Cuando empieza la ejecución del script, se llama a una función `load_dictionary()` que lee el archivo csv y retorna un diccionario con cada `key` que corresponde al idioma y `value` es una lista con cada palabra de ese idioma.

```
{'es' : ['casa', 'mesa', ...], 
'en' : ['house', 'table',...], 
...}
```

En la función menu`()` hay otro diccionario con el formato para cada línea:

```
"numero_opcion" : ["texto de opcion", "idioma1", "idioma2"]
```

Con esos datos es suficiente para construir el menú y comandar el funcionamiento del programa.

```
import csv

def load_dictionary():
    dictionary = {'es':[], 'en':[], 'fr':[]}
    csv_file = open('stack040.csv','r')
    for row in csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=','):
        dictionary['es'].append(row[0])
        dictionary['en'].append(row[1])
        dictionary['fr'].append(row[2])
    csv_file.close()
    return dictionary

def translate(dictionary, opt):
    print(f"\nTraductor {opt[0]}")
    dc1 = dictionary[opt[1]]
    dc2 = dictionary[opt[2]]
    word = input("Palabra a buscar: ").lower()
    if(word in dc1):
        idx = dc1.index(word)
        transl = dc2[idx]
        print("La traduccion es: ", transl)
    else:
        print("La palabra no ha sido incluida en el diccionario")

def menu():
    print()
    print("************************************")
    print("Bienvenido al Diccionario de Ninos")
    print("************************************")
    prmenu = {'1' : ["Español - Ingles", "es", "en"], 
    '2' : ["Español - Francés", "es", "fr"], 
    '3' : ["Inglés - Francés", "en", "fr"], 
    '4' : ["Salir", False]}
    for option in prmenu:
        print(f"{option} - {prmenu[option][0]}")
    while True:
        eleccion = input("Seleccione una opcion: ")
        if eleccion in prmenu:
            break
    return prmenu[eleccion]

# ############################
dictionary = load_dictionary()
while True:
    opt = menu()
    if not opt[1]:
        break
    translate(dictionary, opt)
```

Comment: Yo se que el formato es feo e ineficiente, pero tengo que trabajar con ese, es obligatorio, yo tenia todo el proyecto desarrollado con uno similar al que muestras pero me lo rechazaron

Comment: Listo, entendido @jgl605 Igual lo dejaré como referencia.