# Como puedo modificar una variable local desde una clase en python

Tags: python, poo

Por ejemplo tengo algo como:

```
variable = ""

 class MiClase:
     def unaFuncion():
          condicional:
              #Quiero cambiar el "variable" desde acá
```

Esto con el fin de pasar variable a otro modulo de python. Muchas gracias y me excuso si es ambigua la pregunta.

Comment: Por qué esa variable existe fuera de la clase y no como una propiedad de está ?

Comment: @BetaM Necesito pasar el valor de esa variable a otro modulo, osea cojo en el otro archivo python y le digo que desde el modulo donde está variable me importe esa variable

Comment: No parece que tener una variable global sea la mejor opción y menos si la pregunta es acerca de programación orientada a objetos. Idealmente deberías pensar en cómo abstraer los datos y operaciones de tu programa en forma de objetos que interactúan entre sí.

Comment: @HernánAlarcón Vale pensaré en lo que me dices :), sin embargo disculpa si parezco necio preguntando pero es posible hacer lo uqe propuse? Olvidando claro que tal vez no sea lo adecuado en POO, quiero pasar esa variable importandola a ptro módulo

Comment: Por què no la defines como ámbito global dentro de la clase?

Comment: @Gabitohh ¿Osea dentro de la clase poner global variable? A eso te refieres? No sabía que se podía hacer

Comment: Si, a eso me refiero.

Comment: @Gabitohh no se modifica la variable :(, podrías mostrarme un ejemplo tal vez estoy omitiendo o haciendo algo mal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Como puedo modificar una variable local desde una clase en python

Aclarar que [es mala práctica usar variables globales](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/29177/por-qu%C3%A9-es-considerado-una-mala-pr%C3%A1ctica-utilizar-variables-globales), sin embargo, la única manera de de modificar una **variable definida** en un bloque externo al que se refiere, es de esta manera.

En Python todas las variables por defecto tiene un ámbito local, para extender su ámbito a otros bloques de código se usa la [sentencia global](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement)

> The global statement is a declaration **which holds for the entire current code block.**

Con *bloques de código*, nos referimos a funciones.

```
variable = "sin "

class Clase:
    def metodo(self):
        global variable

        variable += "modificar"
        print(variable)

objeto = Clase()
objeto.metodo()
```

Extender a ámbito global por cada método de la clase no es practico, puedes definir a la `variable` externa como atributo de la clase por medio de `__init__()`.

```
variable = "sin "

class Clase:
    def __init__(self):
        global variable

        self.variable = variable

    def metodo(self):

        self.variable += "modificar"
        print(self.variable)

objeto = Clase()
objeto.metodo()
```

> Esto con el fin de pasar variable a otro modulo.

Dicho esto, te aconsejo encontrar otra manera.

Puedes importar las variables definidas en un archivo `.py` al importar dicho archivo.

```
from modulo import variable #variable
from modulo import * #variable
import modulo #modulo.variable
```

*Como comentario la manera de acceder en el archivo principal*

Espero haberte ayudado.