# ¿Cómo unir tres arreglos en uno? en C

Tags: array, c

No me funciona y la verdad no sé porqué, help.
Se supone que tengo que juntar esos tres arreglos en uno, pero a la hora de correrlo no me funciona. Le cambié unas cosas antes, pero me aparecieron numeros sin sentido que creo que eran direcciones, pero solo quiero juntar esos tres arreglos para que sus elementos estén en uno solo.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int a1[]={3,5,7,9,10}, a2[]={2,4,5,16,19}, a3[]={6,11,20,21,22}, a4[]={};

main(){
for(int i=0; i<5;i++){
        a4[i]=a1[i];
        for(int j=5;j<10;j++){
            a4[j]=a2[j];
            for(int k=11;k<15;k++){
                a4[k]=a3[k];
            }
        }
    }
    
    printf("Se unen los arreglos: ");
    for(int i=0;i<15;i++){
        printf("%d, ", a4[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El código tiene bastante fallas:

**1.** El array `a4` tiene una longitud nula (de `0` elementos), si intentas recorrer ese array generas un [comportamiento indefinido](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comportamiento_indefinido).

```c
printf("%d", sizeof a4); //Resultado: 0
```

**Solución:** La longitud del array debería ser `15`, así que lo debes declarar de esta manera:

```c
int a4[15];
```

**2.** No tiene sentido esos bucles anidados, al parecer, lo que has intentado hacer es lo siguiente:

```c
for(int i=0; i<5;i++)
{
    a4[i]=a1[i];
        
}
for(int j=5;j<10;j++)
{
    a4[j]=a2[j];

}
for(int k=11;k<15;k++)
{
    a4[k]=a3[k];
}
```

De igual manera, el código sigue estando mal, porque estarías [desbordando](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desbordamiento_de_b%C3%BAfer) el array `a2` y `a3`, así que ahí obtienes otro comportamiento indefinido.

**Solución:** Debes restarle un numero a `j` y a `k` para que dé un índice que no esté fuera de rango:

```c
for(int i=0; i<5;i++)
{
    a4[i]=a1[i];
        
}
for(int j=5;j<10;j++)
{
    a4[j]=a2[j - 5];

}
for(int k=11;k<15;k++)
{
    a4[k]=a3[k - 11];
}
```

Por supuesto, el ultimo `for` debe empezar en `10` para incluir el ultimo elemento del array `a3`:

```c
for(int k=10;k<15;k++)
```

### Observaciones:

**1.** Según el estándar de C, la función `main` debe retornar un valor de tipo `int` y ademas, si no va aceptar ningún argumento, debe estar definido de esta manera:

```c
//Con "void" la función no acepta argumentos.
int main(void)
{
    return 0;
}
```

**2.** No uses variables globales si no hace falta. Esto puede provocar que la depuración sea difícil, puesto no sabes en que momento cambia el valor de la variable. Para mas información, mira este [hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/29177/por-qu%C3%A9-es-considerado-una-mala-pr%C3%A1ctica-utilizar-variables-globales).

**3.** Si el bucle `for` solo tiene una instrucción, no hace falta las llaves de apertura y de cierre.

Siguiendo con estas observaciones, el código quedaría así:

```c
int main(void)
{
    int a1[]={3,5,7,9,10}, a2[]={2,4,5,16,19}, a3[]={6,11,20,21,22}, a4[15];

    for(int i=0; i<5;i++)
        a4[i]=a1[i];
        
    for(int j=5;j<10;j++)
        a4[j]=a2[j - 5];

    for(int k=10;k<15;k++)
        a4[k]=a3[k - 10];

    printf("Se unen los arreglos: ");
    for(int i=0;i<15;i++)
        printf("%d, ", a4[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Por supuesto, existe una forma mas fácil de resolver este problema:

```c
int main(void)
{
    int a1[]={3,5,7,9,10}, a2[]={2,4,5,16,19}, a3[]={6,11,20,21,22}, a4[15];
    int n = 0;
    
    for(int i=0; i<5;i++)
        a4[n++]=a1[i];

    for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
        a4[n++]=a2[j];

    for(int k=0;k<5;k++)
        a4[n++]=a3[k];

    printf("Se unen los arreglos: ");
    for(int i=0;i<15;i++)
        printf("%d, ", a4[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

De este modo, evitas inicializar manualmente las variables `j` y `k`.

Answer (score 0):

Ya salió, muchas gracias :)

```
#include<stdio.h>
main(){
int a1[]={3,5,7,9,10}, a2[]={2,4,5,16,19}, a3[]={6,11,20,21,22}, a4[15];

for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        a4[i]=a1[i];
    }
for(int i=5;i<10;i++){
        a4[i]=a2[i-5];
    }
for(int i=10;i<15;i++){
        a4[i]=a3[i-10];
    }
    
    
    printf("\n\nTodos los arreglos en uno: \n");
        for(int i=0;i<15;i++){
        printf("%d, ",a4[i]);
    }
    

}
```

Comment: Acabé de editar mi respuesta, se me ocurrió una solución mas sencilla..