# Introducir incorrectamente los datos 3 veces

Tags: java, netbeans

estoy haciendo un JFrame sobre un login, por ahora con datos estáticos, al introducir los datos mencionados en Usuario y contraseña aparecerá un mensaje de Bienvenido, sin embargo quiero que al introducir incorrectamente los datos 3 veces seguidas se cierre el formulario, ¿Alguien me puede ayudar con eso? Muchas gracias (Programo en Java NetBeans).

Comment: 1. El IDE que utilizas (Netbeans) en este caso no tiene nada que ver con la pregunta. 2. Muestra lo que has intentado hasta el momento: lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Con una variable global que se vaya incrementando en cada fallo.

Comment: ¿A qué llamas *variable global*? No es bueno inducir a [una práctica no recomendada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/29177/29967), por lo general.

Comment: @Bicho porque una "variable global" cuando alcanza con tener un contador en el mismo formulario, y cuando llegas al limite cerrar el programa?

Comment: @gbianchi a eso me refiero.

Comment: @Bicho, ``variable global`` es diferente de ``variable de clase`` y este último es lo que hace referencia gbianchi

Comment: Por favor siempre agrega el codigo que tengas al momento de formular tu pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez esto te ayude como aproximacion en pseudo-codigo:

```
    //declaro variable de clase    
    int cantIntentos = 0;
    
    //Dentro del actionListener del boton "login" de tu formulario:
    if(intento_formulario_fallido) {
        cantIntentos ++;
    }
    
    if (cantIntentos == 3) {
        form.dispose(); //Cierro form
    
    }
```