# Problema con array_push dentro de función

Tags: php

Tengo un problema con la función de `array_push`, si pongo dentro de una función el siguiente código me salta el siguiente error :

> Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given

El código es el siguiente :

```
function materiasPredefinidas(){

    $materia = new Materia("Matematicas");
    array_push($secretaria->materias,$materia); //ERROR
    $_SESSION['materias'] = $secretaria->materias;

    $materia = new Materia("Historia");
    array_push($secretaria->materias,$materia); //ERROR
    $_SESSION['materias'] = $secretaria->materias;

    }

// Llamar a la función.
materiasPredefinidas();
```

Si pongo el código fuera de una función funciona correctamente.

```
$materia = new Materia("Matematicas");
array_push($secretaria->materias,$materia);
$_SESSION['materias'] = $secretaria->materias;

$materia = new Materia("Historia");
array_push($secretaria->materias,$materia);
$_SESSION['materias'] = $secretaria->materias;
```

Comment: Es porque le estás pasando a `$secretaria` "materias", que no tiene ningún valor, ni siquiera es una variable. deberías poner `array_push($secretaria->$materia);` y ya está

Comment: ¿Qué contiene **$secretaria->materias**? ¿Es un array? La función espera como primer parámetro un array y parece que no lo está recibiendo.

Comment: Sí, $secretaria->materias es un array. @PHPMyguel

Comment: No me queda del todo claro. Trata de hacerle un var_dump() en la línea antes de usar el array_push() y péganos el resultado.

Comment: A ver si entonces lo que te falta es el símbolo $ en materias

Comment: Es un problema de **ámbito**, o sea, dentro de la función no existe `$secretaria->materias` porque ese objeto no aparece declarado en ese contexto (el de la función). Si llamas a la función así: `materiasPredefinidas($secretaria);` y cambias la signatura de la misma así: `function materiasPredefinidas($secretaria){   ...    }` debería funcionar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es un problema de **ámbito**, o sea, dentro de la función no existe `$secretaria->materias` porque ese objeto no aparece declarado en ese contexto (el de la función), de ahí el *`null given`*.

Para meter al objeto `$secretaria` dentro del contexto de la función, tienes que pasarlo en parámetro.

Debería funcionar si:

A. Modificas la signatura de la función así:

```
# $secretaria no está en el ámbito de la función
# por tanto debe recibirla como parámetro
function materiasPredefinidas($secretaria){ 

    //... código 

}
```

B. Haces la llamada así:

```
$secretaria = ....                   #La variable está en este contexto
materiasPredefinidas($secretaria);   #Pero no está en el contexto de materiasPredefinidas
                                     #por tanto, tienes que pasársela
```

---

Para más detalles puedes consultar: [¿Cuál es el ámbito y el ciclo de vida «real» de una variable global en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/118062/29967)