# ¿Por qué variables declaradas dentro de foreach pueden ser leídas fuera de éste?

Tags: php, variables

Me encuentro trabajando con `PHP`, pero como vengo de trabajar con `C#` (lenguajes muy distintos). Y como saben, `C#` es muy estricto a la hora de declarar variables.

Mi cuestión es la siguente: Tengo un bucle `foreach` que recorre un array en `php`, por ejemplo:

```
foreach($array as $i => $item){
  $nueva_variable = $item["key"];
}

echo $nueva_variable;
```

En este caso, según mi lógica en `C#`, no podría imprimir la variable `$nueva_variable` ya que solo puede ser usada dentro del bloque en donde se creó.

Pero en `php` al parecer no tiene problema por eso, y puede imprimir el valor de la `variable` incluso si se llama fuera del bloque de donde fue creada.

Por lo tanto eso es lo que aún no termino de entender, el porqué de ese comportamiento, no se me ocurre alguna explicación. Yo creía que por lógica todos los lenguajes aplicaban la misma "regla" con la que `c#`, `java`, etc, trabajan.

Comment: Sugiero que la persona que votó como "basada en opiniones" retire su reporte, ya que no tiene nada qué ver con "opiniones", cuando estoy buscando una respuesta en base a un comportamiento de variables dentro de bloques de código.

Comment: Échale un vistazo a esta respuesta https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/118598/38103

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tiene que ver con el ámbito de las variables. PHP declara sus ámbitos por función, clase o de manera global. Esto implica que se puedan crear variables dentro de bloques como `foreach` o `if` y llamarlas por fuera sin ningún problema. Así está construido el lenguaje. [Aquí se explican a detalle los ámbitos](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.variables.scope.php).